# How to add Google Maps library on Android Things?

Tags: android, google-maps, android-things

I'm developing an app for Raspberry Ppi 3 using Android things.

And in the project...

My app's `androidmanifest.xml` contains

```
uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" /
```

but it couldn't run this app.

I get this message when I run it. (Google Maps installed.)

> Installation failed with message INSTALL_FAILED_MISSING_SHARED_LIBRARY: Package couldn't be installed in /data/app/com.example.androidthings.myproject-1: Package com.example.androidthings.myproject requires unavailable shared library com.google.android.maps; failing!.
>   It is possible that this issue is resolved by uninstalling an existing version of the apk if it is present, and then re-installing.
>
> WARNING: Uninstalling will remove the application data!
>
> Do you want to uninstall the existing application?

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Why don't you uninstall it and reinstall and then see if it works. It happens to me when I download another version of my app and them push the apk from android studio.

Comment: out of interest. why do you need the maps lib on AndroidThings?

Comment: If you have an application use case for maps on Android Things, we'd love for you to tell us about it in a feature request: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/entry?template=Android%20Things%20feature%20request

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Anyway, You can use [MapBox](https://www.mapbox.com/blog/android-things/) on Android Things instead of Google Maps API.

**UPDATE:**

At least from Developer Preview 5 Android Things supports Google Maps (from [Official Overview](https://developer.android.com/things/sdk/index.html)):

> Android Things supports a subset of the Google APIs for Android. The
>   following table breaks down API support in Android Things:
>
> Supported APIs:
>
> Awareness
>
> Cast
>
> Google Analytics for Firebase
>
> Firebase Cloud Messaging (FCM)
>
> Firebase Crash Reporting
>
> Firebase Realtime Database
>
> Firebase Remote Config
>
> Firebase Storage
>
> Fit
>
> Instance ID
>
> Location
>
> [**Maps**](https://developers.google.com/maps/)
>
> Nearby
>
> Places
>
> Mobile Vision
>
> SafetyNet

Answer (score 3):

Maps API isn't available in Android Things.

You can check the the list of supported and unavailable APIs [here](https://developer.android.com/things/sdk/index.html#support_for_google_services).